# how can I use what:= in VBA for like and multiple condition

Tags: excel, vba

I have below code, which is working fine. However I need to know how to use like condition in place of what:',' and multiple search criteria like I need to find ("," "-", "*", etc)

```
Option Explicit
Sub ReplaceDoTwComma()   
        Worksheets("Sheet1").Columns("D").replace _
            What:=",", replacement:=".", LookAt:=xlPart    
        Worksheets("Sheet1").Columns("G").replace _
            What:=",", replacement:=".", LookAt:=xlPart 
End Sub
```

Thanks in advance for help

Comment: What do you mean "Like Condition"? As for multiple criteria, you'll need to use multiple `.replace` lines in VBA for each condition.

Comment: You can use wildcards like `?` for a single character and `*` for a string.

Comment: You could use a regular expression to replace all occurrences of symbols in a given set of symbols by a target symbol, though that would require iterating over the cells with a loop rather than using the `Replace()` method.

Comment: Thanks for the input

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, you can use multiple Replace statements:

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub ReplaceDoTwComma()

    Dim findVal As Variant, replVal As Variant, i As Long, cols As Range

    findVal = Split(", - * test1")  'add items to replace separated by a space

    replVal = Split(". _ ! test3")  'add replacements (same number as findVal)

    With Worksheets("Sheet1")
        With .Range(.Cells(1), .Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell))
            Set cols = Union(.Columns(4), .Columns(7))
        End With
    End With

    For i = LBound(findVal) To UBound(findVal)

        If findVal(i) = "*" Then findVal(i) = "~*"    'escapes special wild char "*"

        cols.Replace What:=findVal(i), Replacement:=replVal(i), LookAt:=xlPart

    Next

End Sub
```